How does the US Congressional Research Service (or analogues) determine relevant topics for research?
I came upon a 2016 CRS report "Internet Governance and the Domain Name System: Issues for Congress" whilst browsing Wikipedia. How does the communication process between members of the legislature and the CRS look like? Alternatively, I would like some sourced information about analogues in other legislatures, for instance the German Bundestag's Wissenschaftliche Dienste or Australia's (where I live) Parliamentary Library.
For example, there was a report published yesterday — "Foreign Leaders Addressing Congress" — in the face of the address by Netanyahu. These reports do not contain mentions of any interactions, e.g. that a report was produced upon specific request by some members. Is there information about the research service holding regular consultations or exchanging correspondence with legislature members?
The Australian Parliamentary Library characterises itself as providing "Customised and confidential research and analysis for parliamentarians, parliamentary committees, and their staff".1 Perhaps very specific requests do indeed take place, but the publications are purposely anonymised?
Sources

1 https://www.aph.gov.au/about_parliament/parliamentary_departments/parliamentary_library/about_the_parliamentary_library


Interesting question, and I believe, answered in The Congressional Research Service and the
American Legislative Process a document that lays out the rationale for, and genesis of, the CRS.

In addition to serving the committees and party leaders of the House and Senate, CRS responds to
requests for assistance from all Members of both houses, regardless of their party, length of service, or political philosophy.


Each Member, as a consequence of the American system of
political parties and elections noted above, is an independent political decision-maker who makes
his or her own judgments about what legislation to sponsor or support. Individual Members or
their staffs request help from CRS, for example, in learning about issues, developing ideas for
legislation, and evaluating legislative proposals made by the President, their colleagues, or private
organizations.

Now, the preface to this document goes on at some length about how the CRS's role is especially important in the context of the US system.  If taken at face value, this would indicate that other countries would have different requirements from their domestic CRS equivalents.
